# jquery contains selector not working

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of inputs like this:

```
coleta[produtos_attributes][1387560503618][codigo]
coleta[produtos_attributes][2315466542152][codigo]
```

when I try to select them using this code from the docs:

```
$("input[name*='[codigo]'")
```

it returns to me an empty array. It doesn't find them.
Can anyone help please?

edit: posting HTML

```
<input id="coleta_produtos_attributes_0_codigo" class="input_text ui-corner-all" type="text" size="30" name="coleta[produtos_attributes][0][codigo]">
<input id="coleta_produtos_attributes_1387560503618_codigo" type="text" size="30" name="coleta[produtos_attributes][1387560503618][codigo]">
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: Your selector as typed is invalid, did you copy it correctly?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/R3Nhq/, even with the typo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Comment: sorry about it. Should've payed a bit more attention to it

Comment: Ok i'm confused, why @j08691's jsfiddle works???

Comment: well.. it doesn't work for me.. I get this on my console: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name*='[codigo]'

throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

Comment: @renatojf works only on chrome apparently, strange! (and IE10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a square bracket

```
$("input[name*='[codigo]']")
```

Comment: These things happen ;)